# My question is whether I can just use simple present tense for different personal pronouns when I give orders

Tags: grammar, tense

Imagine that there are three of us out here and there is an accident. 
I want to take care of the people who got injured, so I talk to one of my friends and say

> > "You and I **stay** here. He **goes** to ask for help and will be back right quick"

My question is whether I can just use simple present tense for different personal pronouns when I give orders or divide jobs to people or in any similar situations that would make me divide jobs.(I think you have got the idea.)

In order to make my point more clear, here is another example:

let's assume that there are three of us at home. I am talking to one person and make a joke to the other, whose name is Richard, and say

> > "I **stay** home, you **stay** home also, and Richard **goes** to buy dinner for us"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to say exactly as you suggested, or you can turn it into a fairly firm suggestion by adding **can**:

You and I **can** stay here. He **can** go to ask for help and will be back soon.

You could alternatively prefix it with "I suggest that...", or use **could** to make it a slightly milder suggestion.

**can** is definitely exactly the right word to use in your second example:

```
You and I **can** stay home, and Richard **can** go to buy dinner for us!
```